# How to generate two pulses one with 60 and other 66 duty cycle at same instant in 2 pins?

Tags: pwm, atmega328

I have to drive two switches one at a duty cycle of 60% and the other at a duty cycle of 66% simultaneously at 50khz frequency. I am using an Arduino Uno ATmega 328.

Comment: Set Timer 1 to waveform generation mode 14, with both outputs in non-inverting mode and `ICR1 = 319; OCR1A = 191; OCR1B = 210;`.

Answer (score 0):

I proposed a few approaches in generating 100kha pwm pulse trains here in response to someone's ask a couple of days ago. The identical code would work for your purpose as well.

It should come up quickly if you do a scan of topics here.

edit: to make it a little bit easier, here is the code I used to generate 50Khz pulse train with 60% and 66% duty cycles.

```
void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  //pinMode(led1, OUTPUT);                      //led1 as output
  //pinMode(led2, OUTPUT);                      //led2 as output
  pwm1topr(F_CPU / F_PWM);                      //set tmr1/pwm frequency to F_PWM
  analogWrite(led1, F_CPU / F_PWM * 60 / 100);  //led1 @ 60% duty cycle
  analogWrite(led2, F_CPU / F_PWM * 66 / 100);  //led2 @ 66% duty cycle
}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
    //digitalWrite(led, HIGH);  // turn the LED on (HIGH is the voltage level)
    //delay(100);               // wait for a second
    //digitalWrite(led, LOW);   // turn the LED off by making the voltage LOW
    //delay(100);               // wait for a second
}
```

and a quick sim confirms its functionality.

[image]

enjoy.

Comment: What's a kha ?  Also, please add link for the previous answer, instead of that copout.  Was it perhaps  [how can i generate square pulse at 50khz frequency to drive two mosfets at a duty ratio .6](http://arduino.stackexchange.com/q/34633), which is almost a duplicate of this question, except for having only one .6 duty cycle instead of a .6 and .66